# Solr delete Index using cURL

Tags: curl, solr

I'm trying to delete all records from Solr.  I can do this in the browser by posting the following URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

However I wish to do it using the commmand line.  I've installed cURL and have tested that the command line understands curl commands.  But when I issue the following command

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

I receive the error

> < was unexpected at this time

I have tried various different variations using single or double quotes to wrap the xml in, but nothing seems to work.  Can anybody shed any light?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add the `commit=true` parameter.

Would be simpler in this way, all you have to do is an HTTP GET request.

`curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try these parameters

```
commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```