# How do I delete all data from a Solr collection?

Tags: solr, cloudera-cdh

I'd like to delete all of the indexed data in my Solr collection, preferably via a shell command on one of the nodes itself.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the shell, use the `solrctl` command with the following options:

`solrctl collection --deletedocs <collection-name>`

Here's the full usage output from `solrctl --help` for reference:

```
usage: /usr/bin/solrctl [options] command [command-arg] [command [command-arg]] ...

Options:
    --solr solr_uri
    --zk   zk_ensemble
    --help
    --quiet

Commands:
    init        [--force]

    instancedir [--generate path]
                [--create name path]
                [--update name path]
                [--get name path]
                [--delete name]
                [--list]

    collection  [--create name -s <numShards>
                              [-c <collection.configName>]
                              [-r <replicationFactor>]
                              [-m <maxShardsPerNode>]
                              [-n <createNodeSet>]]
                [--delete name]
                [--reload name]
                [--stat name]
                [--deletedocs name]
                [--list]

    core        [--create name [-p name=value]...]
                [--reload name]
                [--unload name]
                [--status name]
```

If you don't have direct access, you can use Solr's update services as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722508/how-to-delete-all-data-from-solr-and-hbase), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719860/how-to-delete-solr-indexed-data-by-query-with-curl), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752850/solr-delete-index-using-curl).

Comment: We are using CDH 5.1.3 and I'm using the solrctl utility to deletedocs in my collection. following is the command `solrctl --zk ${ZKHOST} collection --deletedocs ${COLLECTIONNAME}`. The collection is empty. when I looked at /solr/<collectionname>/core_<num>/data/index I see that I have _1.fdt, _1.fdx etc and _2.fdt, _2.fdx etc. seems like a bug to me or I'm missing something

Comment: That's definitely odd.  I know it worked for me in CDH 4.2 and CDH 4.7.  We're in the process of upgrading to CDH 5.3 right now.  I'll add another comment as to whether it works in that version once I can test it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command for command prompt

```html
curl http://<ip_address>:8983/solr/<collection_name>/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8';
```

Comment: I had to add  `?commit=true` to the URL to really delete the documents.